# How to save custom image in database table using REST Api in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, image

**How to save custom image coming from third party platform to save into magento 2 custom table.**

I have just created **REST** **api** for my requirements.

I passed image in **base_64 encoded** string from Thirdparty platform and i got those image **`base_64 encoded`** string in magento 2.

But i dont know how to save image from **base_64 encoded** string into my custom table. what is the procedure for this event.

**Any help will be appericiated.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to create custom module for this functionality .**

**Below are the summarized point for custom module and its code .**

- First i have done the same operation to save category image via rest
  api in magento 2
- Create one observer which called on catalog_category_save_before
  event Then ,You need to create String type of extension_attributes
  for the custom image.
- After that you can pass base64_encoded image data into that
  extension_attributes.
- you need to decode that base64_encoded image and use
  file_put_contents function to create/save image.
- Magento EAV structure will automatically save your image file name
  into database and value for the same if you overrides correctly.

**Now Coming on the code , See below file wise code for more clarity.**

**Events.xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <!-- category save before event -->
  <event name="catalog_category_save_before">
      <observer name="catsaveafter" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Categorysaveimage" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**extension_attributes.xml (Here creating custom extension_attributes for image)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface">
        <attribute code="category_baseimage" type="string">            
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Observer file.php(Ex - Categorysaveimage.php)**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Categorysaveimage implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $_filesystem
    )
    {
        $this->_filesystem = $_filesystem;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {    
        $category = $observer->getCategory();       
        $extensionAttributes = $category->getExtensionAttributes();     
        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {     
            $extensionAttributes = $this->getOrderExtensionDependency();     
        }
        $attr = $category->getData('category_baseimage');

        if($attr !== null){         
            $mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('catalog/category');

            $imgContent = explode(",",$attr);           
            $imgName = $imgContent[0];
            $imgEncodedData = base64_decode($imgContent[1]);
            $path = $mediapath.'/'.$imgName;

            file_put_contents($path, $imgEncodedData);
            $extensionAttributes->setCategoryBaseimage($attr);   
            $category->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
            $category->setImage($imgName); 
        }
        return;
    }

    private function getOrderExtensionDependency() 
    {    
        $orderExtension = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryExtension'
        );   
        return $orderExtension;  
    }

}
```

**Note : As i mention i have done this module to save image of category using rest api , same way you can do as per your need .**

Hope it helps..